# How to find symbol addresses in vDSO given vDSO's address?

Tags: android, c++, linux-kernel, shared-libraries, vdso

I am working on a school research on the Dirty Cow vulnerability. During my research I found some solutions (for example [this one](https://github.com/scumjr/dirtycow-vdso)) that inject some shellcode into vDSO (into the function `__vdso_clock_gettime`).

This solution and all of its derivates use a hard-coded constant as an offset for the symbol `__vdso_clock_gettime` within the vDSO. This constant however is not valid for all versions of the kernel and vDSO (at least not for Android devices).

Is there a better way to find the address (the offset) of a symbol inside vDSO in C/C++? I tried

```
handle = dlopen("[vdso]", RTLD_LAZY);
```

with `[vdso]` being the output of

```
dladdr((void*)vdso_addr, &dlinfo);
LOG("dladdr: %s", dlinfo.dli_fname);
```

with `vdso_addr` found in `/proc/self/auxv`, but I am getting `dlopen failed: library "[vdso]" not found`.

I know vDSO is a system matter and that a normal program should not decide whether to call functions from it or not, but is there some universal way to find the address of the symbol in C/C++ without disassembling every possible version of vDSO and making a database of the addresses?

How does the system get the addresses of symbols during a virtual system call to the vDSO?

Comment: `man 7 vdso` The kernel set it in the auxiliary vector and then call the elf interpreter. I believe information about what is hapening can be find in the efl specification. You could also read the code of µlibC (and documentation associated with it, don't look inside the libc spaghetti plate)

Comment: The manual pages in the section File format say: _"Since the vDSO is a fully formed ELF image, you can do symbol lookups on it (...) Thus, when looking up a symbol in the vDSO, you must always include the version to match the ABI you expect."_ 
But they don't tell how to make a symbol lookup.

Comment: From the man page: *The base address of the vDSO (if one exists) is passed by the kernel
       to each program in the initial auxiliary vector (see getauxval(3)),
       via the AT_SYSINFO_EHDR tag.* Then the elf format is described in [gabi41](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/elf/gabi41.pdf) see section 4 and 5. (this is the general abi, there might have other related informations in the processor specifics abi - psabi) From this description you can infer how to perform symbol lookup. You will find an example of implementation of name lookup in µlibC.

Answer (score 0):

See https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/stable/vdso

"Programs that dynamically link to glibc will use the vDSO automatically. Otherwise, you can use the reference parser in tools/testing/selftests/vDSO/parse_vdso.c"

and

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/tools/testing/selftests/vDSO/parse_vdso.c